# How to open and save excel file in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have one excel file (test.xlsx) which contain a column, say id,  in which I have applied a formula and when I open it manually, value of all ids changes automatically, because of it when I close it, it ask for save the changes.

same I have tried with java code as given below

```html
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str1 = "c:/file/test.xlsx";
        try {


            //open file
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File(str1)));
            System.out.println(wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(1).getCell(0).getDateCellValue().toString());

            //save file
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(str1);
            wb.write(out);
            out.close();

            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File(str1)));
            System.out.println(wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(1).getCell(0).getDateCellValue().toString());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }




output:
Thu Aug 04 01:08:34 IST 2016
Thu Aug 04 01:08:34 IST 2016
```

after executing above code I am not getting any exception

I have verified the result by reading file with help of apache POI.

I want, after saving the file with code new ids should be in Id column as it happening in case of manually open and saving file.

For me it is not working with code.

please suggest

If you are not able to understand the problem then create file like below and open it and close it manually, after that try with code, you will understand the things

[image]

Comment: what is `exceldoc`? That is not defined in the code...

Comment: Define "not working" please, and note that the way to save a workbook (with POI) is something like `wb.write(OutputStream)`, see https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Let's just get back to basic, just pretend you are asking your "question" to some busy colleague. Wild guess: Are you asking how to "update/recompute" the formula before saving with POI?

Comment: yes, same thing I want

Comment: thanks RC, with the help of your comment I have found the solution.

Comment: As per [the Apache POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1023C), you either need to write to a different file to the one you opened from, or do an in-place write. Overwriting the open file via a stream isn't suppored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution, in above code I have to add only one line, please check below

```html
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str1 = "c:/file/test.xlsx";
        try {


            //open file
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File(str1)));
            System.out.println(wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(1).getCell(0).getDateCellValue().toString());

            //FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

            XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);

            //save file
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(str1);
            wb.write(out);
            out.close();

            wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File(str1)));
            System.out.println(wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(1).getCell(0).getDateCellValue().toString());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```